# Reading name ranges from Excel to SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have around fifty names ranges in excel from multiple worksheet. I want to assign each of these rangename value to a variable in SAS. These values in excel rangename is dynamic. I want to make sure that when I run the sas code, it assign the value correctly. Can someone help me how to do this?

Comment: Don't the ranges look like dataset members when you point a libref at the XLSX file?  Trying to assign a range of cells to a variable does not make much sense.

Comment: To a variable in a data set or a macro variable? Assuming each named ranged applies to one cell?